# Modelling recurrent items (expenses) as records with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am writing what could be defined as an accountancy/invoicing app using Rails 5. I am in need of implementing a section that predicts the company's cashflow in the future. So far I've got the following:

- Actual bank movements and balances (in the past), imported from the bank
- Future invoices (income) which are expected to be paid on a certain date
- Future one-time expenses which are expected to be paid on a certain date

Using these three sets of data, I can calculate, for any given date in the future, the sum of: the last known bank balance, plus all the future invoices values coming IN, minus all the future expenses going OUT, so I get, theoretically, the expected balance of the company for any given date.

My doubt arises when it comes to recurrent expenses (or potentially incomes). Given that all of the items I mentioned before (bank movements, invoices and expenses) are actual ActiveRecord records stored in my database, I'm not sure about how to treat the recurrent expenses, for example:

Let's imagine I want to enter a known future recurrent paycheck of a certain employee, which is $2000 every first day of the month.

1- Should I generate at some point the next X entries and treat them as normal future expenses (each with its own ID, date and amount)?

2- The other option I've thought of is having some kind of "declaration" on the nature of the recurrent expense, as in "it's $2000 every day 1 of month until -forever-", similarly to a cronjob. But, if I were to take this approach, I'd like to have an ActiveRecord - similar interface, so that I can do something like:

```
cashflow = []
last_movement = BankMovement.last
value = last_movement.balance
(last_movement.date..(last_movement.date + 12.months)).each do |day|
  value += Invoice.pending.expected_on(day).sum(:gross_amount)
  value -= Expense.pending.expected_on(day).sum(:gross_amount)
  value -= RecurringExpense.expected_on(day).sum(:gross_amount)
  cashflow.push( { date: day, balance: value } )
end
```

This feels almost right but, I'm not sure about how to link the actual expense when it comes with the recurrent/calculated one. How can I then change the date if the expense gets paid the day after it was supposed? I need to have an actual record of each one of those, at least whenever they are "consolidated".

I'm not really sure if I was clear enough with my trouble here, so, should anyone want and have some spare time to help me out, please feel free to ask for any extra relevant info, I'd really appreciate some help, especially if we can find a way of doing this "the Rails way"!

Comment: I would separate future transactions (which would include recurring) with past transactions. Past are settled and real, future are estimated. At any given time your prediction for a future balance is past transactions + future transactions (estimate). You settle exact dates when you create a past transaction and future transactions expire the day they should be settled as a past transaction. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense! However, you're suggesting that future transactions expire the day they should be settled as a past transaction. This is perfect for one-time transactions, as I can even set warnings if there's one that hasn't been settled as past transaction. The problem comes with the recurring ones: how does the logic decide if a certain recurring transaction has happened? With one-time ones I can link both records but with recurrent, I could do it by date, but what if the date doesn't match? (I'm considering that a recurring is represented by just one record with "recurrence". info)

Comment: Recurrent transactions (to infinity) wouldn't expire, associated past transactions, should probably point to the future transaction that originated them, to have some sort of trace, instead of matching by date. There shouldn't be any logic deciding wether a transaction happened or not, the existence of a past transaction would indicate it happened.

Comment: use iCalendar RRules to model recurring events